# Custom qml view

Tags: c++, qml, qt-quick

Can I create some custom view? I have some model(written in C++ inheriting `QAbstractListModel`), which I use in `ListView` and `GridView`. When I do some changes in C++, I can just emit `dataChanged` signal to update my views. Can I connect some QML properties to data from model? `Image.source` for example?

**EDIT 1**

I have `QAbstractListModel` subclass. It contains data about some files. I have created `ListView` in the left of my main window. Click on some row should change view in the right working area. Working area contains detailed information about each file. So, how can I implement this?

Comment: It sounds like what you ant to do should be mostly documented [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html) apart from the bit about showing information in another view but that could be handled with a `MouseArea` in your `ListView` `delegate` and handling the `onClicked`

Comment: @sjdowling Yes, I've already read this :) I have `MouseArea` in my delegate and `onClicked` I save index and change state of right view. It gets information (file_name, size, etc.) from `MyMainModel` which I use for left list. When some changes are happened interactively with a model, left `ListView` is changed according to them after emitting `dataChanged`. But right view, which is not `GridView` or `ListView`, doesn't change and I should use something like `Connections` QML element and emit some `myParamChanged` from C++.

Comment: Using a plain item and bind it to the delegate properties is not an option? As you select a new current item also the values changes and if a change occurs in the model underneath, also the values changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can access whatever part of your C++ class you expose as a `property`:

```
class MyModel : public QAbstractListModel
{    
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString source READ source WRITE setsource  NOTIFY source Changed)
public:
    QString source();
    void setSource(QString s);
signals:
    void sourceChanged();
};
```

Register the type:

```
qmlRegisterType<MyModel>("Stuff", 1, 0, "MyModel");
MyModel model
QQmlContext *ctxt = rootContext();
ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &model);
```

Then in QML:

```
import Stuff 1.0

Image {
    source: myModel.source
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to provide `Q_PROPERTY` to each role, that I want to change. Post was updated.